# How does Ferguson not remember them?

Tags: plot-explanation, sleepers

In the film [Sleepers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117665/) (1996), how does Ralph Ferguson not remember Michael, Tommy or John? I mean, if he didn't recognize their faces, which he probably wouldn't because they're adults now, he must at least recognize their names. Especially considering that Michael is the prosecutor of the case. Ferguson must have heard his name mentioned somewhere and thought it was odd that Michael would be trying to put Tommy and John away.

Answer (score 1):

There must have been hundreds of boys going through Wilkinson Home for Boys, being abused by the guards there. Why would he remember names of the random three of his victims (again, among probable hundreds) from 13 years before?